# Generate dynamic css with option page (ACF)

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently working on an option page (ACF Pro v5) for wordpress that dynamically generates a css file. When I'm testing this locally it works fine; only on a live server the dynamic css couldn't generate by wordpress.

Am I missing something? Is there something white the rights that wordpress can't write the file. I've a clean custom-style.css placed in the right folder with chmod 777.

This is the code I've written in my functions.php:

```
function generate_options_css() {
$ss_dir = get_stylesheet_directory();
ob_start(); // Capture all output into buffer
require($ss_dir . '/styles.php'); // Grab the custom-style.php file
$css = ob_get_clean(); // Store output in a variable, then flush the buffer
file_put_contents($ss_dir . '/Library/css/custom-styles.css', $css, LOCK_EX); // Save it as a css file
} add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'generate_options_css' ); //Parse the output and write the CSS file on post save
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/Library/css/custom-styles.css' );
```

Comment: Where is this Library folder stored and what is the chmod value of this?

Comment: @radscheit In the root of the theme folder and i've changed the chmod manually to 777. nothing happend.

Comment: Code seems to be correct. Is PHP logging a failure?

Answer (score 0):

May be your live server is running with a child theme and your local setup has no child theme. This is why your local version is working and the live is not working. The most probable reason is that you are using both funtions `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory();` and both will point to the same `'/Library/css/custom-styles.css'` file only if your current active theme is not a child theme.

So, it is wiser to use any one based on your demand and not both together :)